# A consistent set of formulas

Tags: logic

In a logic system, a set $\Sigma$ of formulas is said to be inconsistent if $\Sigma \vdash \bot$, and consistent otherwise.

Does it mean that $\Sigma$ is consistent if and only if $\Sigma \vdash \top$? Thanks.

Comment: Think about it.  If a set of formulas is inconsistent, does it mean it doesn't imply True?

Comment: What kind of logic would not have $\Sigma \vdash \text{ True}$?  Specifically, what about $\emptyset \vdash \text{ True}$?

Answer (score 4):

Every set of first-order sentences proves $\mbox{True},$ even the empty set; so, you're not negating correctly. If done correctly, you will see that 'consistent' equals 'does not prove false.' Lets just spell out the definitions to make this as clear as possible.

**Definition 0.** $\Sigma$ is *inconsistent* iff $\Sigma \vdash \mbox{False}.$

**Definition 1.** $\Sigma$ is *consistent* iff not ($\Sigma$ is inconsistent.)

Therefore, $\Sigma$ is consistent iff not ($\Sigma \vdash \mbox{False}.$)

Answer (score 2):

Nope. We actually have something weirder at first glance. A set of sentences (in a language $L$), $\Sigma$ in FOL is consistent iff there exists a $\phi$ in $L$ such that $\Sigma \not \vdash \phi$. Odd, right?

This follows from the fact that if $\Sigma$ is inconsistent, then for all $\phi$ in $L$, $\Sigma \vdash \phi$. How does this work? Well, first you need to show that if $\Sigma$ is inconsistent, then $\Sigma \vdash \psi \wedge \neg \psi$ for some $\psi$ in $L$ (This is actually an 'iff' statement, and I will leave this portion for you).

Since $\Sigma \vdash \psi \wedge \neg \psi$, we have that:  $$\Sigma \vdash \psi \implies \Sigma \vdash \psi \vee \sigma \implies \Sigma \vdash (\psi \vee \sigma) \wedge \neg \psi \implies \Sigma \vdash \sigma $$

Hence, if $\Sigma$ is inconsistent, then $\Sigma$ proves every sentences in the language.

Now, we show that $\Sigma$ is consistent iff there exists a $\phi$ in $L$ such that $\Sigma \not \vdash \phi$. One direction is trivial.

Suppose that there exists $\phi$ in $L$ such that $\Sigma \not \vdash \phi$. Then $\Sigma$ cannot prove anything of the form $\phi \wedge \neg \phi$ (by the proof above). Since if it did, then we could prove everything (including $\phi$). Hence, $\Sigma$ does not prove any contradiction and therefore, by definition, is consistent.

$\mathbf{Edit}$ Note that if $\Sigma$ is an set of sentences, then $\Sigma$ proves all valid sentences.

Comment: Maybe it's obvious and I need some coffee, but could you elaborate on the third "$\Rightarrow$"

Comment: @dstathis It's [disjunctive syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism). if you know that $\psi$ or $\sigma$ is true, and you know that it's not $\psi$, then it must be $\sigma$.

Comment: But we assumed $\Sigma \vdash \psi \wedge \neg \psi$, So does $\neg \psi$ still imply not $\psi$?