# Is this theorem about soundness or completeness?

Tags: logic

$\def\True{\top}\def\False{\bot}$
In [Kaye's math logic](http://books.google.com/books?id=EOjT_j-qOnsC&q=7.12#v=onepage&q&f=false), $X$ is a set of propositional letters, and $BT(X)$ is the set of Boolean terms over $X$. There is a theorem about its valuation on the binary Boolean algebra $\{\True, \False \}$:

[image]

1. Why is it named "completeness theorem"? I think it is not about
   "completeness" but about "soundness", because completeness is from
   $\Sigma \vDash \True$ to $\Sigma \vdash \True$, while soundness is from
   $\Sigma \vdash \True$ to $\Sigma \vDash \True$:

   [image]

   [image]
2. In particular, [I am not sure if "$\Sigma_0$ is consistent" means
   $\Sigma_0 \vdash \True$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877357/a-consistent-set-of-formulas).

Thanks.

Comment: Regarding *consistency* [see also your previous post], the answer is : **NO**. See page 65 : "we will say that $Σ$ is *inconsistent* if $Σ \vdash ⊥$, and *consistent* otherwise." Thus (properties of negation) : $\Sigma$ is *consistent* iff it does **not** prove "the false", i.e. iff $\Sigma \nvdash \bot$.

Comment: Regarding **Completeness Th**, see page 89 : "**Theorem 7.13 (Completeness Theorem, second form)** : Let $X$ be a set, and
suppose that $Σ ⊆ BT(X), τ ∈ BT(X)$ with $Σ \vDash τ$. Then $Σ \vdash τ$, i.e. there is a formal derivation of $τ$ from $Σ$", which is exactly what you expected. It is proved as a corollary of the **first form** of the Completeness Theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kaye's theorem is that if a set of sentences is syntactically consistent, there is a valuation which makes the sentences all true together.

That trivially implies that if some sentences $\Gamma, \neg\phi$ can't all be true together, then $\Gamma, \neg\phi$ aren't consistent.

In other words, if $\Gamma \vDash \phi$ [= no valuation makes all $\Gamma$ true and $\neg\phi$ true as well] then $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ [for if $\Gamma, \neg\phi$ are inconsistent, then by reductio  $\Gamma \vdash \phi$].

So yes, Kaye's result is indeed a version of the completeness theorem.

I should add -- as you are asking a vast number of questions here -- that this is entirely routine, and is explained in any number of books. For the standard Henkin-style proof of completeness goes precisely via showing that any any consistent set of sentences has a model. Perhaps you should try putting your brain into gear, and consulting more than one text when you hit something you find difficult, before troubling math.se quite so often.

Comment: Thanks. How do you like Kaye's book? What level would you classify it into, with what similar books?